# Indy UDP sending and responding simple strings

Tags: delphi, udp, indy, delphi-10-seattle

I am using Delphi 10.0 Seattle.

I'd like to send requests to a UDP server and then read the server response, which is a simple string:

```
Client side:send('12345')
server side(onread event or whatever):if received string =  ('12345') then 
send ('jhon|zack|randy')
else disconnect;
```

The length of the response string is variable.

**The server is running on a well opened network with open connection (dedicated vps).
 The client is not the same, it is behind routers and secure networks (not forwarded).**

So far, I can only send the request from the client:

(uc=idUDPclient)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s:string;
begin
  if uc.Connected =False then
    Uc.Connect;
  uc.Send('12345');
  uc.ReceiveTimeout := 2000;
  s:=uc.ReceiveString() ;
  ShowMessage(s);
  uc.Disconnect
end;
```

Server side  (us=idUDPserver)

```
procedure TForm1.usUDPRead(AThread:TIdUDPListenerThread;const AData: TIdBytes;ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  ShowMessage(us.ReceiveString());

  if us.ReceiveString() = '12345' then
  begin
    ShowMessage(us.ReceiveString());

    //respond with a string to the client immediately (behind a routers) how ?
  end;
```

I don't know if TCP is better, and how to use it.

Android will be involved.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: http://s19.postimg.org/5qat163eb/SCRS_751.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not using the `TIdUDPServer.OnUDPRead` event correctly. You need to get rid of the calls to `ReceiveString()`, they do not belong in there. Use the `AData` parameter instead, it contains the raw bytes of the client's request.  `TIdUDPServer` has already read the client's data before firing the event handler.

If you need the bytes in a `string`, you can use Indy's `BytesToString()` function, or `IIdTextEncoding.GetString()` method.

To send a response back to the client, use the `ABinding`parameter.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.usUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := BytesToString(AData);
  //ShowMessage(s);
  if s = '12345' then begin
    ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, 'jhon|zack|randy', ABinding.IPVersion);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect this is it